# How to Set Up Virtual Host for Vue CLI 3 Project

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I want to be able to access my Vue project from `http://pbdev` instead of `localhost:8080`. I am familiar with creating virtual hosts in Apache, but I'm unclear on how to do this with a Vue CLI 3 project.

Thus far, I have put this in `/etc/hosts`:

```
# Vue Hosts
127.0.0.1:8080  pbdev
```

And I put this in `vue.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: false,
  devServer: {
    host: 'pbdev',
    port: 8080,
    https: false
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
INFO  Starting development server...
10% building modules 1/1 modules 0 activeevents.js:167                            
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND pbdev
  at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:57:26)
Emitted 'error' event at:
  at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1505:12)
  at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:57:17)
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The `:8080` in `/etc/hosts` is the problem, just do `127.0.0.1  pbdev`

Comment: Ah, brilliant! @EricGuan if you want to post that as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:8080` in `/etc/hosts` is the problem, just do `127.0.0.1 pbdev`

Happy Vueing!

Answer (score 2):

What a great question! Thankfully the Vue CLI 3 makes it fairly simple with a `--host` flag where you can pass a custom host and `--port` for a custom port. You shouldn't have to configure Apache or a custom web server.

The Vue CLI guide has some details: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#vue-cli-service-serve.

Comment: Thanks! :) What I did almost worked. I just mistakenly included the port number in my `/etc/hosts` file. By specifying it in `vue.config.js` file, I don't have to specify it over and over each time I start the server. It's working great now.